# Redirect old URL's to new URL pattern

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop, redirect

Hi I want to change my current product URL structure to a new one but I want to keep my old ones working because of people who have linked to my products.

How can I do this without manually creating a 301 redirect for each product?

Comment: Seriously? Do you want to create a redirect for every single product? I not you must create some kind of rule in your htaccess: IF old_url THEN redirect to new_url with the same parameters. Hugh task. Good luck.

Comment: Be more specific, what is your old and new url structure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Prestashop version you have, just tried in a 1.6.1.6
You can you this override:

```
<?php
class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
{
    protected function loadRoutes($id_shop = null)
    {
        parent::loadRoutes($id_shop);

        $language_ids = Language::getIDs();

        if (isset($context->language) && !in_array($context->language->id, $language_ids)) {
            $language_ids[] = (int)$context->language->id;
        }

        foreach ($language_ids as $id_lang) {
            foreach ($this->default_routes as $id => $route) {
                if($id == "product_rule")
                    $this->addRoute(
                        'product_rule2',
                        '{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.xhtml',
                        'product',
                        $id_lang,
                        $route['keywords'],
                        isset($route['params']) ? $route['params'] : array(),
                        $id_shop
                    );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I used a second rule for xhtml (without this override it gave a 404). You can change {id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.xhtml to the rule you have, then change the rules in SEO to want you want the new one to be.

Answer (score 0):

Please write your ps version. If you use 1.5 or above?

Do you use this structure now {category:/}{id}-{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html ? or 
{category:/}{rewrite}{-:ean13}.html or this {category:/}{rewrite}.html

please write more details

depends on it just make htaccess rule
([0-9]+) for id
(.*) for rewrite
and please use RedirectMatch permanent
and set to the result by $1, $2, etc

that guide must help to understand the htaccess url rewriting https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/